# Python GTK+ 3 on Windows 10

Tags: python, gtk

I've installed latest version of `pygi` on my **Windows 10 64-bit** laptop. When I try the first tutorial program I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'

I don't know what is the cause of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have installed PyGObject from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/). During installation, you have to manually select GTK+ libraries. They aren't installed automatically with the base packages.